# Short and elegant introduction to Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I am preparing a course on Nonlinear Analysis, and I need to teach the most important facts about Sobolev spaces to my students. I know most books on this subject, from Brezis' to Adams', from Mazya's to Leoni's.
But I wonder if there you know a **very** short introduction, a chapter or a little book that you would define *delightful* for a beginner. Of course I do not need advanced topics: just the basics, the embeddings and the most important inequalities.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Chapters 5 and 6 of Zimmer's *[Essential Results of Functional Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=UM07W0rM7RIC)* is what you're looking for. It contains an elegant introduction to the basics on roughly 50 (small) pages.

Here's the table of contents:

[image: Table of contents]